# To show: the sum of the elements of S is equal to the sum of the elements of T

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let A = {1,2,3,...,1867}, and let B be a subset of size 15. Prove that B contains two subsets S and T such that
1) S and T have empty intersection.
2) The sum of the elements of S is equal to the sum of the elements of T

So I am stuck in this question, I have tried using literal numbers from the set A,  but nothing checks out. 
I tried taking T as multiples of 3 and S as non-multiples of 3. 
But the sum of [T]=sum of [S] does not check out.

Any help/hint would be highly appreciated. 
My assignment is due tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: You are screwed

Answer (score 1):

The subsets of $B$ are going to have a sum of elements between $0$ and $15\times 1867$, this number is smaller than $2^{15}$, this is the number of subsets of $B$.

By the pidgeongole principle there must be two subsets $S$ and $T$ so that the sum of their elements is the same. Notice that the subsets $S'=S\setminus(S\cap T)$ and $T'=T\setminus(S\cap T)$ also have equal sums, and they have empty intersection.

Comment: I don't get why it's 15x1867. I am guessing when we say subset of size 15 it means B has 15 elements which could be anything from {1,2,......,1867)

Then, S and T could have any combination of elements such that they have equal sums. Is that correct? If you could give me a detailed explanation, that would be great. I actually would love to understand how to write the proof. I have never written proofs before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: yeah, but any subset of $B$ can have at most $15$ elements, and all of them are less than or equal to $1867$, so the maximum possible sum is less than $18\times 1867$